# Finding the smallest number of substrings to represent a set of strings

Tags: string, algorithm, set

I would like to find the set of non-overlapping substrings that can be concatenated to represent a given set of strings. Suppose this given set of strings is

```
abc0def
zabc1def
abc2defg
```

then the smallest set of non-overlapping substrings that can be concatenated to form the full set of strings above is

```
abc
def
0
1
2
g
z
```

To clarify: By non-overlapping I mean that no member of the set starts or ends with the same sequence of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use the strings to build a directed graph, with the characters as the vertices and arcs pointing from the characters to the following characters. For any vertex with indegree of two or more, remove all the incoming arcs. Similarly, for those with outdegree of two or more, remove all the outgoing arcs. With those removed, the remaining components of the graph are path graphs representing the substrings; just follow the path to build the substrings.

You will also need to introduce dummy vertices for the start and end of the strings. This avoid problems with, e.g., `abcde` and `bcd`.

Comment: How does this approach work if the set of strings are abcd, abc, and bcd?